# Cloud SDK: gcloud sql instances describe throws error 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_id] command is showing "HTTPError 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist."

I tried to include the --project="Project name" but it didn't work.

in instance_id i put my instance id of gcloud sql

admin1 ~/Desktop/practice_app/heroku-test-app master $ gcloud sql instances describe [instance_id]
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) HTTPError 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist.

Comment: Try with project if, not name.

Answer (score 2):

1. First you need to identify you Cloud SQL INSTANCE_id. You can find this information in Cloud Console. To know more, [please check documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info) .

    In case of doubts it is last part of the instance connection name, that has 3 parts
   `<project-id>:<zone-name>:<instance-id>`
2. Please check that you [initialized cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing#run_gcloud_init) properly, using correct project ID where Cloud SQL instance is located. 
   Please also be aware that [project name is not project-id](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects). That is probable cause that your `--project=` flag did not work. 
   You can initialize cloud SDK using following command: `gcloud init`.
3. Then you can use:

   `gcloud sql instances describe <instance-id> --project=<project-id>`

   If my project Id is: test-id, and cloud sql instance: cloudsql1 complete command is:

   `$ gcloud sql instances describe cloudsql1 --project=test-id`gcloud